# will input default to a type of text?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a rather random question but here we go. I am working on some trickery with Javascript for a plugin. Say I have an input that looks like this:

```
<input type='cc' id='cc' class='' />
```

Obviously the type `cc` is not a valid input type. Does html automatically just default the unknown type to `text`, or will it have an adverse effect?

Comment: "text" is the default if you don't specify anything (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). I'm not sure if there is behaviour defined if you add an invalid type. It might be up to the browser to handle it. Can you avoid adding the type? Or is this some hook for something?

Comment: If you are using the type as a hook, it might be better to use data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quoting directly from [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html)

> An input element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as an [input element with its type attribute set to "text"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text).

[image]

Comment: so even if I specify a type that is not recognized it will still default to text type on the processing side.

Comment: @MarkHill: Yes, **but** if you use CSS selectors like `input[type=text]` (for styling, or to look up elements with `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`, etc.), note that they **won't** be found. Of course, in your "trickery" case, `input[type=cc]` would (because the attribute's there, even if it's invalid).

Comment: In the question there is an unknown type attribute, but this quote adresses another problem. Does it mean that an undefined type is treated as a lack of type attribute?

Answer (score 3):

If the value of the input type is not known or not supported in the browser, it'll default to "text".

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** If you pass an invalid value for an *enumerated attribute*, it will use the *invalid value default* instead. If that doesn't exist, it will use the *missing value default* instead.

The input `type` attribute doesn't define a *invalid value default*, but it defines a *missing value default*, which is `text`.

Hence using an invalid value will default to `text`.

---

From the WHATWG HTML spec:

> #### [2.4.3 Keywords and enumerated attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#keywords-and-enumerated-attributes)
>
> Some attributes are defined as taking one of a finite set of keywords. Such attributes are called enumerated attributes. [...] In addition, two default states can be given. The first is the **invalid value default**, the second is the **missing value default**.
>
> [...]
>
> If the attribute value matches none of the given keywords, but the attribute has an *invalid value default*, then the attribute represents that state. Otherwise, if the attribute value matches none of the keywords but there is a *missing value default* state defined, then *that* is the state represented by the attribute. Otherwise, there is no default, and invalid values mean that there is no state represented.

[`<input>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-input-element) specifies a *missing value default*, which is `text`:

> The *missing value default* is the Text state.

Comment: Hey is it possible to change this default state to button?

Comment: @anshabhi: I don't know for sure but I would assume "no".